# Flutter get_it and FutureBuilder not working with hot reload

Tags: flutter, hot-reload, flutter-provider

The app below works as expected, but unfortunately it does not work with hot reload. I would like to know how to get hot reload working with it.

All the code does is simply to wait for a particular `Future<String>` to be available, and then to display that string on screen. While it's waiting, a progress indicator is displayed.

As I said, that works as expected, but the problem is that if I change anything (I mean just simple cosmetic stuff) and hot reload kicks in, the app will just sit there forever showing the progress indicator because the `connectionState` stays in `ConnectionState.waiting` mode.

This is what the code does in more detail:

I register a `String` object as a singleton in `GetIt`. Since that string is wrapped in a `Future`, the code has to wait for it to be ready before it can be registered.

(In the real code, I am loading a JSON string from an asset. That's why it's in a `Future`.)

A `FutureBuilder` waits for the string singleton to be available by waiting for `GetIt` to signal a property called `readyFuture`.

When the string becomes available, the `FutureBuilder` displays it on screen. Until then, a `CircularProgressIndicator` is displayed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() async {
  final str = await Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => "hello");
  locator.registerSingleton(str, signalsReady: true);
  locator.signalReady(str);
}

void main() {
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: locator.readyFuture,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
          Widget result;

          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
            case ConnectionState.active:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              result = Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              break;
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError)
                result = Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
              else
                result = Center(child: Text('${locator.get<String>()}'));
              break;
          }

          return result;
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have these dependencies in my pubspec.yaml:

```
  get_it: ^3.0.1
  provider: ^3.1.0
```

Comment: What exactly happens on hot reload in that case? I use it very much like that and didn't have a problem yet

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that GetIt uses a broadcast stream, `GetIt.ready`, to signal that it is ready. The problem with a broadcast stream is that the signal is lost on hot reload.

Another, separate problem is that if there are no listeners to the `GetIt.ready` broadcast stream, then the ready signal will be lost. So there is a race condition there: you have to make sure that the FutureBuilder is listening to `GetIt.ready` before the ready signal is sent, and that may not be possible in general.

The work-around I came up with was to use a `Completer` object as the ready signal. (See `locatorReady` in the code below.) I added a listener to the `GetIt.ready`, and that signals the `Completer` object.

The `FutureBuilder` waits on the `Completer.future` property.

(I am a Flutter novice, but it seems to me that using a broadcast stream in GetIt was not a good choice. A `Completer` would be better I think.)

This is the updated code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;
Completer<void> locatorReady = Completer<void>();

void setupLocator() async {
  final str = await Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 8), () => "hello");
  locator.registerSingleton(str, signalsReady: true);
  locator.ready.listen((_){locatorReady.complete();});
  locator.signalReady(str);
}

void main() {
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: locatorReady.future,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
          Widget result;

          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            result = Text('Awaiting result ...');
            break;
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              result = Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            else
              result = Text('Result: ${locator.get<String>()}');
            break;
          }

          return Center(child: result,);
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for letting me know. I will revisit the signal part soon.

Comment: What are you thinking about this as new API
  Future<void> allReady(); and 
  Future<void> isReady<T>({Object instance, String instanceName});
instead of exposing the Future or Stream directly? With this way we get more control and I can easily correct the problem above.

Comment: This is a great answer, worked well for my `FutureBuilder` when using `Firebase.initializeApp()`.